# My android project in Eclipse disappeared?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wanted to create .apk file from my Android project in Eclipse, so I klicked on File --> Export --> Export Android Application. I filled required fields and I clicked finish. After that I received an error and all my application files disappear, I only have a file called "gen [Generated Java Files] and I cant open it.

I tried to search my app files manually in Windows Explorer but all is gone...

Now I don't have app files and even .apk

Where is my application?

Comment: did you search the destination folder where the app was supposed to be exported?

Comment: Use your system Search to find some file from the project.

Comment: We need a bit more info. Files are gone in Eclipse AND filesystem? BTW, you had no backup at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try to look for it in your workspace directory.

If you don't know where that is, click File > Switch Workspace, and you'll be able to see the location.

Or you could go to:

```
\eclipse_directory\configuration\.settings\
```

Open `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` with a text editor (e.g. Notepad).

Look for `RECENT_WORKSPACES`. You'll find the location of your workspace there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Free Recovery to recover your deleted file.
Try it soon before anything write on that disk sector.